# Adding extra options to right-click menu

Tags: 11.10, menu

Are there any more options that can be added to the right click menu in Ubuntu? e.g when right clicking in nautilus or desktop?

Comment: One way you can do this by adding a PPA with 'Nautilus Actions Extra' described here on OMG!Ubuntu: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-add-actions-emblem-support-back-to-nautilus-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. The first thing you need to do is install the Nautilus Actions application:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
   ```
2. After it is installed, press the super(windows) key then search for Nautilus Actions you will find the icon click on it then you should now see the **Nautilus Actions** main screen

   [image: Adding Shortcuts to the right click menu in Ubuntu]
3. Click the **Add** button and you should see the Add a New Action screen

   [image: Adding Shortcuts to the right click menu in Ubuntu]
4. Fill out the **Menu Item & Action** properties with whatever you would like in your right click menu.  Above, you can see I am using VLC as an example.

   Next, click on the **Conditions** tab.

   [image: Adding Shortcuts to the right click menu in Ubuntu]
5. Under the Conditions tab you need to make sure that Both is selected under “Appears if selections contains”.

   Next, click on **Advanced Conditions**

   [image: Adding Shortcuts to the right click menu in Ubuntu]
6. First, uncheck the “File / Local Files” box.  Second, in order for the menu items you add to appear every time you right click, you will need to add a blank entry under the Advanced Conditions.  To do this, click on the + and erase “new-scheme” and “new-scheme description” so that both entries are blank.
7. Click **OK**.
8. You now have added your first right click menu item.  In order for the item to appear on your right click menu, you need to restart the nautilus daemon.

   ```
   killall -HUP nautilus
   ```

Now you should be able to see the VLC media player on the right click menu.

[image: Adding Shortcuts to the right click menu in Ubuntu]

To continue adding more items to the menu, repeat steps 3 through 8 until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was not able to run all the new and old packages of `filemanager-actions`,`nautilus-action`, etc to run with Ubuntu 23.10

So my solution at the end was to install [nautilus-python](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus-python) and write [my own extension nautilus-poem](https://github.com/rokdd/nautilus-poem). The extension works with a configuration file so that you need only to install once and can configure multiple actions and conditions:

```yml
- label: Right click for submenu
  tip: Click me now
  subitems:
     - label: 2nd level right, nest me more?
- label: Flatten selected folder
  conditions:
     - "directory_count > 0"
  click: /do-something.sh {POEM_FILES}
```

Since I started development some days ago it has some limitations, but feel free to contribute or contact me in case you need something implemented