# Dropdown menu is showing less items , when I right-click on the desktop

Tags: menu

How would I add an office application on a drop-down menu (from right-click)? When I right-click inside folders and on desktop it shows only a couple items, I want a Windows-like drop-down menu. Please how would I make this as default?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to add liber-office application on right click menu. One of the best part of Linux OS is it is an extension independent. You can right click open new document and rename it to file.doc or file.ods or file.odt or file.ott or file.txt(for text document) whatever you want just add extension. So no need to have so many items on right click menu everything goes with a single file.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I edited this first (so I hope I got what you were asking right) You would like to add an application to your drop-down correct?

If you check this post, it may help, but I am not sure how up to date/out of date the program is.

[Adding extra options to right-click menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88480/adding-extra-options-to-right-click-menu)

It looks like some people have used the above mentioned for 14.04 (nautilus-actions).

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions-extra
nautilus -q`

- Above is from this link:  http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/nautilus-actions-extra-pack-of-useful.html*

You will also need to run the actual program with elevated privileges.