# How to Add Options to the Mouse Right Click Menu in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, menu, customization

I would like to add some options like New Text Document,Refresh and also some Options to the Mouse Right Click Menu in Ubuntu 14.04.

How to Add  and Where to add, such options to that, using by terminal or any means?

But I prefer Terminal and Screenshots regarding to that.

Comment: The right click menu in what?

Comment: *"Create New Document"* already is there... for other entries see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus

Comment: I Mean New Text not New Document @Takkat

Answer (score 5):

There is a useful program for this called `nautilus-actions`. This will let you customize the right-click menu. Just install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Launch it by using from the Ubuntu Dash menu (start searching for nautilus). It is called Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool and has an icon the shape of a shell.

[Nautilus Actions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Rqi.png)

It is quite easy to use, just use the add button in the top left-hand corner. Define the action (right-click menu's name) icon and terminal command along with a few other things.

For more information, follow the guide at https://askubuntu.com/a/88485/555667.